# Connect array with dictionaries via cocoa bindings

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I want to populate my `NSTableView` via cocoa bindings.

I created `ViewController`:

```
class GlobalLogViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
    dynamic var items:[NSDictionary] = [["name": "1"]]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.

    }    
}
```

Then created `ArrayController`:

[image]

Then in `tableView`:

[image]

And in table column:

[image]

But it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the table column's NSTextField's Value to Table Cell View, not Array Controller. The Controller Key should be blank, and the Model Key Path should be objectValue.name.

[image: Binding for column NSTextField]

This is demonstrated about 20 minutes into the WWDC 2011 Session 120 video [View Based NSTableView Basic to Advanced.](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011-120/)